# Prevent users from Skipping Lead Status but allow to skip just one non mandatory step

Tags: validation-rule

I am using a Validation rule to Prevent users from Skipping Lead Status but I recognized that one step isn't mandatory, Unqualified and can be skipped or marked at any moment.

Here is the formula I used to prevent skipping the Status but I do not know yet how to allow users to adapt that for the explained requirements.

```
ISCHANGED(Status) &&  ( 

CASE( Status,   

"New",1,  

"Preliminary analysis",2,  

"Unqualified",3,

"Add to XL",4,

"Qualified",5, 

6) 
-

CASE(PRIORVALUE(Status),

"New",1, 

"Preliminary analysis",2, 

"Unqualified",3, 

"Add to XL",4, 

"Qualified",5, 

6)) <> 1
```

I would thank any help or hint I will receive in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `Unqualified` from consideration and renumber the Lead Statuses

```
ISCHANGED(Status) && NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status,'Unqualified')) ( 

CASE( Status,       
 "New",1,  
 "Preliminary analysis",2,  
 "Add to XL",3,
 "Qualified",4, 
 5) 
-

CASE(PRIORVALUE(Status),
 "New",1, 
 "Preliminary analysis",2, 
 "Add to XL",3, 
 "Qualified",4, 
 5)) <> 1
```

Comment: Hi Cropedy,

Thanks for your help, sadly wont work, when I go to select the Unqualified Stage the Validation Rule is triggered.

Should be able to be picked/skipped, rest has the order has you pointed aswell...

Comment: sorry about that, I added a condition to exclude `Unqualified`

Comment: Hey cropredy, thanks for the hint, I tried already this formula after you answered me at first, I got rencommended to use an IF statement but even when I tried give me and Error with CASE.... thats a tricky VR, didnt find anything on the whole itnernet yet, or at least on 1 week of researches.